# How can I force Open Tasks to display in Kanban view

Tags: tasks, kanban

I want to view tasks in the Kanban view.  I'd like to not have to click Display As ... Kanban every time I view my Open Tasks.  Can I make this setting permanent? [image]

Comment: can you post a picture about your ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn’t possible yet, but you can vote for the idea here: [default to Kanban](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LkbYQAS)

Comment: Upvoted this idea.